# vi replacing with two question mark instead of one question mark

Tags: regex, vi

```
<?php echo $form->create(); ?> 
   <?php echo $form->hidden('id'); ?> 
   <?php echo $form->input('name')); ?> 
   <?php echo $form->submit('Save'); ?> 
<?php echo $form->end(); ?>
```

I want to replace  "; ?" with " ?".

I used the vi command ":%s/; \?/ \?/g" to do that. I got the following output

```
<?php echo $form->create() ??> 
   <?php echo $form->hidden('id') ??> 
   <?php echo $form->input('name')) ??> 
   <?php echo $form->submit('Save') ??> 
<?php echo $form->end() ??>
```

Actually, I need the following output.

```
<?php echo $form->create() ?>
   <?php echo $form->hidden('id') ?>
   <?php echo $form->input('name')) ?>
   <?php echo $form->submit('Save') ?>
<?php echo $form->end() ?>
```

Can you give the explanation for this strange behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `\?` is the vi-regular-expression for the normal `?` in other program's regular expressions.

You can look at `:h regex` to verify this (or more precisely `:h E61`).

So when using `; \?` you match `;` (no space) and `;<space>` (one space). From these matches the greediest one (see E61 - as many as possible) will be replaced with a `?` thus resulting in two question-marks (one new one and the old one) when there is a space present.

The correct expression would be: `s/; ?/ ?/g`

EDIT: Fixed explanation to be more precise.

Answer (score 1):

`:%s/; \?/ \?/g`

`; \?` match `;<space>` zero or one time, and it replaces them with `?`.
So you get the original `?` with another `?`.